# Application.Current returning null before shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-5

I have a Page inside a NavigationWindow in WPF. When I press the close button (the X) I need to execute some code when the Page closes. Right now in my code-behind I've got this:

```
public partial class CompactLayout : Page
{
    private readonly CompactLayoutViewModel _viewModel;

    public CompactLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _viewModel = new CompactLayoutViewModel();
        Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted += OnShutdownStarted;
        //instead of Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted I've also tried: this.Unloaded += OnShutdownStarted;         
    }
    
    private void OnShutdownStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.releaseServerViewModel();
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel constructor I have an Event Handler called `ImageUpdate` (`ClientProxy` is the class where I raise the event):

```
ClientProxy.ImageUpdate += async (sender, args) => await ImageUpdateAsync(args.image,args.fps);
```

Declaration of `ImageUpdateAsync` in the ViewModel:

```
private Task ImageUpdateAsync(byte[] img, int fps)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            // things occurr
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // things occurr v2
        }
    }));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I get the error **System.Windows.Application.Current.get returned null** from the call `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` at `ImageUpdateAsync` before `_viewModel.releaseServerViewModel` is called. If instead of `Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted` I use `this.Unloaded += OnShutdownStarted` the error ocurrs even before `OnShutdownStarted` executes.

How can I fix this code so the Page unloads before this error can happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewModel
{
  private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;

  private Task ImageUpdateAsync(byte[] img, int fps)
  {
    _dispatcher.Invoke(() => {/*...*/});
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```